# Is it possible to use create-react-app with laravel 7.x

Tags: laravel, create-react-app

I've been using create-react-app for quite a while and I recently need to build a backend via laravel.  Is it possible to use create-react-app, it's `npm run start` development workflows, etc to communicate with a laravel backend?

I can see that laravel already has a package.json file and from what I can tell, the react packages do not use create-react-app.  I have seen an npm package, but it doesn't appear to be current and is probably not compatible with Laravel 7.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not needed if you are going to build the SPA and the backend in the same directory structure because laravel has its own workflow using [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix) and you can take advantage of the framework [Scaffolding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend) but if you are planning to only connect to an existent Laravel Backend you can create your react app with `create-react-app` command and connect to laravel using axios,fetch or something like that

Comment: I'm working my way through the documentation you listed.  Will mark as answer when / if I can get this working, sorry for the delay.  And thanks! (upvoted)